# Why cant one-way speed of light be measured using a timer start that is electronically connected at midpoint?

Tags: special-relativity, time, time-dilation, measurements, one-way-speed-of-light

Why can't one-way speed of light be measured using a timer start that is electronically connected at midpoint?

I'm sure I'm missing something, but why can't an experiment be built with two timers that are connected electronically by a start switch half-way between light start and stop points? Would not using using a different medium than light to sync the clocks avoid errors from multidirectional light travel and time dilation?

Comment: I can't see why this question should be closed. There are peer-reviewed research papers in physics about the 1-way vs. 2-way speed of light. Isotropy of space is taken as a postulate when we derive special relativity, and it's perfectly legitimate to ask what happens if we drop this assumption.

Comment: Perhaps the original poster of the question can give a bit of context, like what the one-way speed of light means. Many people haven't heard of this (unless they've watched https://youtu.be/pTn6Ewhb27k)

Comment: More on [one-way speed of light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-way-speed-of-light)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is wrong with these ways of measuring one-way speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/712688/)

Comment: @user34722 it is a legitimate question which has been answered over and over and over again. It is about as frequently duplicated as a question can be. I can only link to one duplicate in the official close reason, but see the tag search in Qmechanic’s comment for many others

Comment: I see. The original reason for closure said that the question was off-topic for Physics StackExchange. Looks like that's been updated.