# Clarification about the one-way vs two-way speed of light

Tags: speed-of-light, one-way-speed-of-light

I've just watched [*Why No One Has Measured The Speed Of Light* by Veritasium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTn6Ewhb27k), but I haven't really understood why this debate exists.

The reason for my misunderstanding, I believe, is that the whole video hinges on examples of light moving between 2 points, i.e. making the way forward and the way along the single line connecting the two points.

So ok, I get that that means that a possible alternative to $c_{forward} = c_{backward} = c$ is $c_{forward} = c/2 \,\,\wedge\,\, c_{backward} = \infty$.

But what if make light travel along a square, with 45° mirrors? If two sides are in the same absolute direction as before, then the speed of light will be $c/2$ and $\infty$ along those sides.
$$
c = \frac{4}{\frac{1}{c'} + \frac{1}{c''} + \frac{1}{c'''} + \frac{1}{c''''}} = \frac{4}{\frac{2}{c} + \frac{1}{c''} + \frac{1}{\infty} + \frac{1}{c''''}}
$$

Which leaves the speed of light unknown across the other two sides, as long as $1/c'' + 1/c'''' = 2/c$

But so we have that same problem again, just along two directions which are not that of light going away or towards me but... from left of me or from right?? (I'm imagining myself ortogonal to the plane of the screen.)

```
                       c/2
                 /----------->\
                 ^            |
                 |            |
    me      c''''|            |c''
                 |            |
                 |            v
                 \<-----------/
            ∞
```

Sure a solution would be $c'' = \infty\,\,\wedge\,\,c'''' = c/2$, but $c'' = c/2\,\,\wedge\,\,c'''' = \infty$ would be a solution as well, and why should I prefer one to the other, given the symmetry?

---

Is the trick in that none of these 4 sides is on the line of my sight, hence light will... vary speed along the sides in a symmetric way such that all fits with $\frac{1}{c'} + \frac{1}{c''} + \frac{1}{c'''} + \frac{1}{c''''} = \frac{4}{c}$?

Comment: Please read Dale's excellent answer about the Einstein synchronisation convention, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/591436/123208

Comment: "I haven't really understood why this debate exists." - There is no debate; there is just a popular YouTuber who made a video about a subject that he doesn't really understand. The [one-way-speed-of-light] tag was created to organize the questions that showed up here in the wake of that video's publication. It didn't exist before.

Answer (score 2):

This question is very closely related to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/590983/can-one-way-speed-of-light-be-instantaneous/591436#591436), [that](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/712688/what-is-wrong-with-these-ways-of-measuring-one-way-speed-of-light), and [the other](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/754621/are-the-non-standard-one-way-speed-of-light-conventions-just-transformations-of) questions as well as all of the questions in the [one-way-speed-of-light tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-way-speed-of-light).

However, I think that the focus in this question on the OWSOL in multiple spatial dimensions is something that has not been covered explicitly in previous answers that I am aware of. I will focus on that aspect as the rest has already been thoroughly discussed elsewhere here.

Anderson deals with this concept explicitly in his paper [Conventionality of synchronisation, gauge dependence and test theories of relativity](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0370157397000513). In that paper he begins with a fairly typical (although high quality) treatment in a single spatial dimension. Then in section 2.3 he extends his analysis to multiple spatial dimensions. He promotes his synchrony parameter $\kappa$ to a vector field $\vec \kappa$ which allows the OWSOL to vary in every direction, and also from place to place. The corresponding coordinate transform is $$t'=t-\vec \kappa \cdot \vec x/c$$$$\vec x'=\vec x$$ where $\vec x=(x,y,z)$ is the spatial position. And the OWSOL in the direction $\hat n$ is $$c(\hat n)=\frac{c \hat n}{1-\vec \kappa \cdot \hat n}$$ where $\hat n$ is a unit vector.

> But so we have that same problem again, just along two directions which are not that of light going away or towards me but... from left of me or from right??

It is not a problem, but it is an additional degree of freedom in specifying our OWSOL convention, or equivalently our synchronization convention. The fact that we have even more freedom to choose our convention simply further strengthens the idea that the OWSOL is a matter of convention.

> why should I prefer one to the other, given the symmetry?

In this specific case we set $x$ to be the forward direction and $y$ the left direction. Then since $c_{forward}=c((1,0,0))=c/2$ you have $\vec \kappa = (\kappa_x,\kappa_y,\kappa_z)$ where $\kappa_x=-1$, but $\kappa_y$ is undetermined. However, in this case we can insist that $\kappa_y=\kappa_z=0$. This, in turn, comes from insisting that $|\vec \kappa|\le 1$. From $$c(\hat n)=\frac{c \hat n}{1-\vec \kappa \cdot \hat n}$$ if $|\vec \kappa|>1$ then $c(\hat n)$ would be negative in some direction, but speed is never negative. But in general we could choose $\vec \kappa$ such that none of its components are zero.

Comment: Since you mention _in this specific case_, I think you're referring to my example. Would you mind clarifying what (x, y, z) are with resepct to that? Also, what is the x vector?

Comment: I updated the answer with explanations

Comment: People have been doing physics in arbitrary coordinate systems since 1915. Why did Anderson write a paper about a less general treatment of the issue in 1998?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point, in my opinion, is that to measure the speed of anything, including light, we need a pre-synchronized set of clocks. These clocks can be evenly spaced (say, separated by 1 meter) and should remain at rest w.r.t. each other.

If we fulfill this condition, then we are ready to measure the one-way speed of light. However, it is light itself that we use to synchronize these clocks in the first place. Now, if you think about it, you will see that there is no way to synchronize two clocks that are separated by a non-zero spatial distance without requiring that the transmitted light be received back by the source. But in doing this, we average out the speed of light in both the direction and hence lose the information of the one-way speed of light.

[This paper](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/5001/pg5001-images.html#ch9) by Einstein explaining this himself might be helpful (see chapter 8). Here is a quote from the same chapter.

"*That light requires the same time to traverse the path $A \rightarrow B$  as for the path $B \rightarrow C$  is in reality neither a supposition nor a hypothesis about the physical nature of light, but a stipulation which I can make of my own freewill in order to arrive at a definition of simultaneity*.”

Comment: Rømer famously measured the speed of light without transmitting anything.

Comment: I don't see why you can not synchronize clocks in a one-way sense. Just assume you have several clocks in a line recording the arrival time of the light signal.  If all the clocks would already be synchronized, we would get an exactly linear plot of the arrival times vs. distance (assuming obviously that the speed of light is constant throughout the path and also that all clocks are identical). So we just need to have a look at the arrival time for each clock and adjust then their times such that we get a linear plot. All clocks will then be synchronized.

Comment: @Thomas you assume all clocks are already synchronized and that is the problem.

Comment: Rømer didn't synchronize his clocks (the rotation of Earth and the orbit of Io).

Comment: Are you referring to this page:= (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B8mer%27s_determination_of_the_speed_of_light#:~:text=By%20timing%20the%20eclipses%20of,value%20of%20299%2C792%20km%2Fs.)? As I understand, this is pre-relativity which means no questions were asked regarding the meaning of simultaneity. The relativity of simultaneity changes things.

Comment: @S_G I did not assume all clocks as synchronized. I said that IF they are synchronized, we know that the times registered by each clock should be a linear function of the distance x i.e. t=x/c. If 3 clocks at distances x= 0, 1 and 2 show the times t= 0, 15 and 10  respectively on arrival of the signal, you know that the clocks are not all synchronized. But you can easily synchronize them by subtracting 10 from the reading of the second clock, which gives you t=0, 5 and 10. Clock synchronization is just a matter of correcting the reading of the clock. And this does not require two way signals.

Comment: @Thomas clock synchronization is the big issue here. I think you need to carefully consider how you would synchronize clocks in the first place (knowing that simultaneity is relative).

Comment: @S_G Clock synchronization as such has nothing to do with Relativity. After all, you are synchronizing clocks at rest (as you stipulated yourself), and you can use any kind of signal for this, not only light. So as per my argument above, your sentence "*there is no way to synchronize two clocks that are separated by a non-zero spatial distance without requiring that the transmitted light be received back by the source*" is clearly incorrect

Comment: @Thomas we need light for synchronization as it has the same speed for all frames of references. If you disagree then please provide a source for other forms of synchronization.

Comment: @S_G You said "*These clocks can be evenly spaced (say, separated by 1 meter) and should remain at rest w.r.t. each other.*"  

For two clocks at rest w.r.t. each other at distance x, the time t  to travel this distance  is t=x/v  for *any* kind of signal with constant speed v *if* the clocks are synchronized  (a different (constant) speed v does not change the synchronization condition as the relation is still linear.) If one of the clocks is not synchronized, it will show an offset$ \Delta t$ from this relation, which you can make zero by correcting that clock correspondingly.

Comment: @S_G The light round trip scenario is merely something that Einstein set up to derive his Lorentz transformation, because otherwise it is not possible to perform the mathematical tricks he used in his derivation (see my web page https://www.physicsmyths.org.uk/lorentz.htm for more).