One-way speed of light through long tube
Let's assume we have a long, narrow tube perpendicular to a wall that emits light (similar to the ones doctors use to look at radiology films). On the other side of the tube there is a sensor (mounted on a wall), that measures the intensity of the light coming through the tube. (no other light can reach the sensor, it is masked in some way).
Now we make the tube move, describing a circle of a certain radius (parallel to the two walls). The sensor is large enough to cover the trajectory of the tube). Both the source of light and the sensor are static, they don't move at all.
As the speed of the tube increases, assuming it is long and narrow enough, the intensity of the light that passes through it should decrease, until at some point, no photon makes it to the other end, and the sensor eventually reads 'zero'.
No clocks and no mirrors are required, and it's not even necessary to reach the speed when the reading is zero, the variations of the readings as the speed of the tube increases should be enough.
Why couldn't this be used to determine the one-way speed of light?

Does this answer your question? Can One-Way Speed of Light be Instantaneous?

I don't see how this setup is fundamentally different from any other experiment that claims to be able to measure the one-way speed of light. The problem is, as always, the clock synchronization between source and detector. There are many such questions across this site.

@VincentThacker both the source and detector are static, no synchronization is required between them. When photons stop making it to the other end, we have the final result.

That is false. You need a synchronization convention to determine whether two spatially-separated clocks are showing the same time, which requires the one-way speed of light. It does not matter whether they are moving or not. All you have to do is take a look at the many such questions that have already been asked and answered here.

there is no clock in this setup, the sensor measures the intensity of light, and there is a continuous flow of light - we don't need to know when a photon was emitted; we just need to know whether a (or any) photon hits the sensor or not, it doesn't matter when.

How does the tube move in a circle parallel to the two walls? You said that the tube is perpendicular to the walls.

This question is answered by https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/590983/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/712688/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/754621/ See especially my answer in the second link

@PM2Ring the circle itself (the trajectory) is parallel to the wall, sorry!

OP: To determine the speed of light, as was said, you need to create some correlation between events that happen at the source $S$ and events that happen at the detector $D$.  The mere fact that you have two clocks separated by any distance requires an assumption about the one way speed of light, in order to compare them.  I highly encourage you to read the beginning few sections of Einstein's original paper On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies. He goes over this in detail, and it is very approachable to someone with high school education.

Regarding your proposed setup, let's say you spin up your tube to some rev per minute $\omega$ and see no light impacts at the detector. How would you use that information to calculate the speed of light?

@RC_23 The OP didn't say the tube is spinning. But I'm still unclear on the geometry of this setup, and I have no idea how one is supposed to use it to measure the speed of light.

It is revolving in a circle (call that spinning or not if you will), and I think it is intended to be like Fitzeau's gear device for measuring the speed of light. But presumably the assumption is that light is emitted as individual photons with a known, regular frequency of emission (e.g. 20,000 photons per second), which is not the case.

This experiment seems to be analogous to the one leading to the so-called aberration of stars when they are observed through a telescope from earth. Due to the speed of earth, a telescope has to be tilted forward by a certain angle from the true direction of the star in order to see the star. Otherwise the light from the star would not pass the telescope. This  aberration has been used by James Bradley in the 1700s to estimate the speed of light pretty accurately. Wikipedia
