Why can't one-way speed of light be derived with simple wave mechanics?
If we understand light as having a frequency and wavelength, why not just multiply them to get the speed, this doesn't require mirrors or synchronised clocks. I'm 100% sure this doesn't work, but I couldn't find any resources online explaining why it wouldn't work.

How would you be measuring the frequency and wavelength?

wavelength by inteference patterns, and i assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that we had some easy way to know the wavelength of light. If theres no way to measure light frequency then thats the answer, i just assumed there would be some way to detect the frequency of oscillations in the electric and magnetic field.

No, we are trying to get you to understand that your question will run into troubles at measuring frequency and wavelength when you actually try to do it. The fact of the matter is that if you fully understood SR, you will see that the OWSoL is unmeasureable as a direct consequence of SR. It is part of how SR works.

This question is similar to: Can One-Way Speed of Light be Instantaneous?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/712688/what-is-wrong-with-these-ways-of-measuring-one-way-speed-of-light and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/754621/are-the-non-standard-one-way-speed-of-light-conventions-just-transformations-of
